# Kernel make generates “ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xdc0): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_s_enable'”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiler-errors, linux-kernel

OS is Ubuntu 20.10 Kernel Source is linux_5.8.0-59.66

I am porting kernel modifications from Centos 7 Rhel 7.9 to Ubuntu.

The original unmodified Ubuntu kernel source compiles and runs cleanly on this machine. The compiler set up seems to be functioning properly.

My current problem is related to a system call I've added. The error generated is -

```
LD      .tmp_vmlinux.btf
ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xdc0): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_s_enable'
BTF     .btf.vmlinux.bin.o    
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
LD      .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1
.btf.vmlinux.bin.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
make: *** [Makefile:1163: vmlinux] Error 1
```

I have searched and googled this original error "undefined reference", found possible fixes which have not worked.

Here are the steps I used to add the system call, which originally worked on Centos 7 and RHEL 7.9.

Modified /SOURCE-DIRECTORY/include/linux/syscalls.h commentng out the original line and adding the reference to __64 (including a blank line above it)-

```
asmlinkage long __64_sys_s_enable(int s_enable_flag);
//asmlinkage long sys_s_enable(int s_enable_flag);
```

Modified /SOURCE-DIRECTORY/arch/x86/include/asm/syscalls.h adding -

```
440     64      s_enable        sys_s_enable
```

The fields are delimited by TAB, and I did not add any blank lines.

Created the source directory and files - /SOURCE-DIRECTORY/s_enable containing s_enable.c. s_enable.c in it's entirety is

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
extern int s_enable_flag;

asmlinkage long sys_s_enable(int i)
{
//       printk(KERN_INFO "In ORIGINAL SYSCALL s_enable\n");
         s_enable_flag = i;
         return 0;
}
```

And added the appropriate syscall directory to the Makefile.

```
core-y          += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ s_enable/
```

And ran "sudo make".

I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong in that the "make" works with the original kernel source, and the system call I am trying to add has worked on the other mentioned distros.

Thanks for any input you can provide.

UPDATE 07-18-2021
I made the following changes on 07-17-2021 in order to use SYSCALL_DEFINE1.

SOURCEDIR/include/linux/syscalls.h
The reference to sys_s_enable has been commented out.

```
//asmlinkage long sys_s_enable(int s_enable_flag);
```

SOURCEDIR/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl
"64" changed to "common"

```
440     common  s_enable        sys_s_enable
```

SOURCEDIR/Makefile has been edited to remove SOURCEDIR/s_enable from core-y

```
core-y          += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/
#core-y          += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ s_enable/
```

Copied/edited the original s_enable.c into SOURCEDIR/kernel/sys.c using SYSCALL_DEFINE1

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(su_enable, int, i)
{
    extern int s_enable_flag;
    s_enable_flag = i;
    return 0;
}
```

The compile command was sudo make -j4 and took 12-15 hours which is somewhat normal.

The error was

```
LD      .tmp_vmlinux.btf
ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xdc0): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_s_enable'
```

Thanks - Roger

Comment: "Modified /SOURCE-DIRECTORY/arch/x86/include/asm/syscalls.h adding ..." - Do you mean that you actually have modified table [arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.18/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl)? Anyway, `asmlinkage  ...` is a wrong way for declare and define a syscall function. Instead, use `SYSCALL_DEFINE*` macro (in your case, `SYSCALL_DEFINE1`) when define your syscall function.

Comment: I have attempted to use SYSCALL_DEFINE1 however I am not doing it correctly.  The error generated is the same.  Details of the changes have been appended to the original post due to length.

Comment: In the table you place `sys_s_enable` as a syscall name. Why do you use **other name** (`su_enable`) in the SYSCALL_DEFINE1 macro?

Comment: The example I found indicated to do that.  Should I use sys_s_enable in the SYSCALL_DEFINE1?  I'm only asking because the compile will 12-15 hours to complete.  Happy to try, but that would be the reason for a delayed response from me.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to create our own system call a newer version of Linux `__x64_sys_`

Here is the comment from `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` in the begin

> The **x64_sys**() stubs are created on-the-fly for sys**() system calls

so that our system call function name might start the prefix with `__x64_sys_`, here is the sample code for your own function.

```c
asmlinkage long __x64_sys_s_enable(int i)
{
//       printk(KERN_INFO "In ORIGINAL SYSCALL s_enable\n");
         s_enable_flag = i;
         return 0;
}
```

Then the `include/linux/syscalls.h` file might need to add this prefix name which aligns with the function name

```c
asmlinkage long __x64_sys_s_enable(int i);
```

the system-call entry we can just use your expectation function name `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`

```
440     common  s_enable       sys_s_enable
```

We can recompile your kernel if we follow those steps, and we might get a successful build.